# Android emulator running on Android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

Is it possible to develop an Android emulator that runs on Android? This app will only need to support running other Android apps in it.

[update]
Potential interesting use is that we can use it to stream android games to users, like how browsers handle flash games - currently, to start playing a new game in app store, there are many manual steps (download, install, confirm ...), and with this emulator, users will only need to press once to start playing a new game, all manual steps will handled automatically in the background, no more hassles of downloading and installing.

Comment: Your question isn't too clear mate. Please edit it so that it throws more light on what you exactly want to know.

Comment: This should not be a principal problem. I don't think there is a market for it.

Comment: Why you need Android Emulator on Android device??

Answer (score 0):

**No it is not** possible to Do Such thing, But you can Start Customizing it Today Only, by getting the Android Code.

Answer (score 0):

Does seem like a product without a need if im being honest. I don't know anyone who owns an Android device or Apple device for that matter that does not understand they need to go to market and click a button to download and install. It really isn't that difficult is it? And to be fair, in order to get your application, users are going to have to go through those exact steps are they not?

Jason

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you'll see the potential of an app like this if you compare it to music or video industry - imagine you are on Youtube, and you have to manually download the video and install it on your pc to start enjoy it, what a hassle!